# Remote Computer Control for Windows 7 Computer Behind Firewall That is Always On

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, remote-desktop

I'm looking for a solid free program or service that will let me remote into a computer behind a firewall at any point in time.

I've tried join.me, but am having issues. It also requires a person at the computer to grant you control of the screen.

Can anyone make some recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [www.teamviewer.com](http://www.teamviewer.com), a free solution for personal use! The best imo! It can also be setup to have a permanent address and password without having anyone at the remote computer to grant you access.

Answer (score 0):

Try [www.LogMeIn.com](http://www.LogMeIn.com) or [www.LiveMesh.com](http://www.LiveMesh.com)